# How to compile busybox for arch=arm on macos M1?

Tags: linux, macos, apple-m1, busybox

I have successfully cross-compiled linux-4.9.229 kernel for arch=arm on Macos M1, with steps like these:

```bash
$ brew install gcc-arm-embedded --cask
$ brew install cmake autoconf libtool gcc automake openssl
$ brew link openssl --force
$ make multi_v7_defconfig
$ export ARCH=arm
$ export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-none-eabi-"
$ make -j 8
```

After that, I was trying to cross-compile busybox for arch=arm, but I got err like this:

```bash
$ export ARCH=arm
$ export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-none-eabi-"
$ make defconfig
$ make -j 8
  CC      applets/applets.o
In file included from include/libbb.h:13,
                 from include/busybox.h:8,
                 from applets/applets.c:9:
include/platform.h:164:11: fatal error: byteswap.h: No such file or directory
  164 | # include <byteswap.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:198: applets/applets.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:372: applets_dir] Error 2
```

I saw that besides `byteswap.h`, I also lack `endian.h`:
[image]

What can I do to solve this? please~

Comment: `arm-none` is directly contrary to saying you want to build against your cross-compiled Linux kernel; the "none" is the "which OS?" slot in the triple.

Comment: That said, personally, I'd steer far clear of using Homebrew here. See https://nix.dev/tutorials/cross-compilation.html

Comment: (what's your actual intended target? I don't see a lot of folks targeting 32-bit armv7 unless they have a very specific platform -- an Android phone or such -- in mind).

Comment: (with Nix, you can ask for `pkgsCross.armv7l-hf-multiplatform.busybox` out-of-the-box and it'll download all the cross-compilers, kernel headers, &c needed to build you busybox for armv7; but `none` makes no sense in the OS part of the triple as a target for busybox -- it absolutely _requires_ an OS. Certainly, the Linux kernel doesn't run on another kernel, so `none` makes sense there, but building kernels and building userspace tools to run on those kernels are two different things).